# How would I know in my service when user touched the back key?

Tags: android, back

I have an Activity and a service running in background. I want to know when user click the Back Key(when my activity is running) in my service so that I can do something in my service. Except override the onKeyDown, do I have an another way? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can override the [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()) method and in that method call the service / send a message to it.

Comment: I know I can make it in this way. I want to know is there an another way to make it? More clearly. I don't want to add more code in my acitvity, except for that code startservcie().

Comment: More clearly: no. How should that work? The service is a completely independent entity. It knows nothing of the activity, and for good reason. You _have_ to add code. That's how things work. You cannot expect a service to kind of mind read your activity's lifecycle...